# Bootstrap - in <li> - formatting columns that are responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In list elements (Bootstrap: <li>) I would like to format a line in columns. Each line consists of e.g. 4 data elements, each put in its own column. I don't want to use a table because of responsiveness requiremnts.

A way of doing this (in a rather static way) is shown below. Is there a better way to do this? For brevity I put the style element in the HTML code. This way would even increase the height of a <li> element if a data element spreads across 2 lines (on small devices).

```
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="height:3em">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">{{ useraccess.name }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">{{ useraccess.requestDate | date:'MM-dd' }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">{{ useraccess.requestAction }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">{{ useraccess.argument }}</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" style="height:3em">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">{{ useraccess.name }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">{{ useraccess.requestDate | date:'MM-dd' }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">{{ useraccess.requestAction }}</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">{{ useraccess.argument }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `display:flex` on **.list-group-item** container and set a fix **width** to it beyond which it shouldn't grow as well as you can set a **min-height** if you want the height to grow dynamically as per the requirements.

```css
.row ul li{
list-style-type:none;
}

.list-group-item{
display:flex;
width:80%;
justify-content:space-between;
flex-direction:row;
flex-flow:row wrap;
min-height:3em;
}

.items{

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="items">Name1</span>
      <span class="items">Date1</span>
      <span class="items">Action1</span>
      <span class="items">Arg1</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="items">Name2</span>
      <span class="items">Date2</span>
      <span class="items">Action2</span>
      <span class="items">Arg2</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap responsive grid:**

```css
div{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="list-group-item row" >
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">Name</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">Date</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Action</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Arg</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-group-item row">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">Name</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">Date</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Action</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Arg</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is growing in lines as expected. 
In the above example I have 4 columns with Bootstrap. Can you do the same with those 4 columns? In my browser and tool, the 4 data items are not structured in columns.

Comment: @tjm1706 You can just make use of them instead of bootstrap columns altogether which needs you to mention the sizes for each column, if you want them responsive for all resolution viewports. Just make sure that the classes name are not predefined bootstrap ones.

Comment: Can you put your suggestions in your example? So, structuring in 4 columns. For very small devices each <li> should have 2 lines of 2 columns.

Comment: @tjm1706 Using flexbox, they can wrap in 2 lines but not directly, each element will wrap individually as the viewport is shrinked. So, I fixed your bootstrap code, the problem with your code was, the class="row" has to be applied directly to the parent container of the column containers.

Comment: Yes, the below example was exactly the best answer. Superb! Marked as the Answer and +1!

Comment: @tjm1706 No problem :)